# what is m2m_changed signal alternative for one to many(foreign key)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

so I have a model A which is a foreign key in model B, and I have another model C
what I need to do is once B changes from A admin inline I want to get the sum of all B instances related that A and update another model C

so here are the steps I want to do:

1 - (B1,B2,B3) have A1 as fk_a  all of them when A1 admin form is saved

2- I want wait for all of them to finish save() then I get the sum of their quantity and do something with it in (C1,C2,C3)

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=20)

class B(models.Model):
    quantity = IntegerField()
    fk_a = ForiegnKey(A)
    
    def save():
        sum_of_similar_b = B.objects.filter(fk_a=self.fk_a)
        similar_c = C.objects.filter(fk_a=self.fk_a)
        update_model_c(sum_of_simlar_b, similar_c)
```

I tried post_save() signal but it's called before the foreign keys are updated
and tried A save() same.

tried m2m_changed signal without "through" but it doesn't get triggered